# SSH asking for passphrase although ssh-agent / keychain is running

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, pppd, keychain

**Disclaimer:**

It would be very nice to read this question thoroughly before marking it as duplicate. I have read dozens of other questions (here, at superuser.com, serverfault.com and so on), all dealing with SSH not finding /dev/tty, *but none of them with relation to `keychain`*, which actually should prevent this problem.

**Having said this:**

I have a Linux (Debian stretch) router which is connected to the Internet via `pppoe`. My provider gives me a dynamic IP address which changes from time to time. Whenever this happens, the router should run a script on another host via SSH.

I have correctly set up SSH on the router and the other host, using public key authentication. The SSH keys are protected by a passphrase.

Furthermore, I have set up `keychain` as advised [here](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain). According to my understanding of this page (and others), `keychain` "provides" the same `ssh-agent` process to any SSH client; when I am logging in, it starts `ssh-agent` (if none is running yet) and asks (or makes ssh ask) for the passphrase(s); from then on, the SSH keys are in `ssh-agent`'s memory and readily available to other processes.

This works with the following exception:

I have put a script into `/etc/ppp/ip-up.d`; that script contains (among others) the following lines:

```
eval `/usr/bin/keychain --noask --agents ssh --eval id_rsa_ipupdate`

ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa_ipupdate root@re.mo.te.ip '/path/to/remote/command'
```

Although the script itself gets executed as expected every time the provider assigns a new IP address, the SSH command fails, i.e. the script on the *remote* host doesn't get executed. It took me a while to debug this, but after making `pppd` log its debug messages in a separate file, I finally found the reason. Some relevant lines from pppd's debug messages:

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:BZSkP9mMIB+cCi5WfgYnqT2QmskTgsKHsWuNXHxIQu0
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:BZSkP9mMIB+cCi5WfgYnqT2QmskTgsKHsWuNXHxIQu0
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug2: no passphrase given, try next key
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

So SSH does not find /dev/tty, which is probably normal, given that it is executed from within `pppd` in this case and thus can't read the passphrase from the keyboard. So far, so good.

But the key point is: **Why does SSH (obviously) want to read the passphrase from the keyboard although an `ssh-agent` is running, managed by `keychain` and having the key readily available?**

Please note the first line in the script snippet above. It should make sure that `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` are set and exported correctly.

Please note also that the script works perfectly (without asking for a passphrase) when I run it from the command line.

To make things absolutely clear: I first log in into the router. As I have set up `keychain` as advised on its homepage, I am immediately asked for the passphrase(s) when logging in. When then calling my script from the command line, it works as expected without asking for the passphrase. But when the script is called by `pppd`, the SSH line fails.

Could anybody please explain why SSH wants /dev/tty although it could load the keys from ssh-agent, and how to get around that problem?

P.S. Yes, I can live with the fact that the script will inevitably fail after the router has rebooted, until I log in at least once :-)

**EDIT 1**

I have done further research and noticed the following: The line

```
eval `/usr/bin/keychain --noask --agents ssh --eval id_rsa_ipupdate`
```

from the script above definitely creates a second `ssh-agent` process when the script is executed by `pppd` due to a change of the public IP address. That means that `keychain` does not find the first one (which has the SSH keys available) for some weird reason.

Again, this only happens when the script is executed by `pppd`; when I call the script from the command line, everything is fine.

I am now thinking about opening a bug report or something like that. By the way, my `keychain` version is `2.8.2`.